# How Can I Output Non-Escaped Element Tag In XML?

Tags: python, xml, html-entities, python-2.5

I have a Python script that I have inherited and my issue is that right now I have a chunk of text in a `paragraph` variable that contains anchor tags. For example:

```
This is text with a <a href="http://somewebsite.com">Link</a> in it.
```

What I'm required to do however is convert the anchor tags to the `apxh` name space so the above line should look something like this:

```
This is text with a <apxh:a href="http://somewebsite.com">Link</apxh:a> in it.
```

The problem is the way I have it above is outputting:

```
This is text with a &lt;apxh:a href=\"http://somewebsite.com;\"&gt;Link Text;&lt;/apxh:a&gt; in it.
```

My guess is that when I'm running the for loop on the `paragraph`, I need to some how find all anchor tags and text and do something like `etree.Element("{%s}a" % nm["apxh"], nsmap=nm)` but I'm not really sure

**This is the current script:**

```
def get_news_feed(request):
    articles = models.Article.objects.all().filter(distributable = True)

    nm = {
            None: "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
            "ap": "http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/aptypes",
            "apcm": "http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apcm",
            "apnm": "http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apnm",
            "apxh": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
            }

    doc = etree.Element("{%s}feed" % nm[None], nsmap=nm)

    for article in articles:
        entry = etree.Element("{%s}entry" % nm[None], nsmap=nm)
        content = etree.Element("{%s}content" % nm[None], nsmap=nm)
        content.set("type", "xhtml")

        div = etree.Element("{%s}div" % nm["apxh"], nsmap=nm)
        for paragraph in article.body.replace("&amp;", "&").split("\n"):
            par = etree.Element("{%s}p" % nm["apxh"], nsmap=nm)
            par.text = paragraph            
            par.text = paragraph.replace("<a", "<apxh:a")            
            par.text = par.text.replace("</a", "</apxh:a")  
            par.text = cleanup_entities(par.text)
            div.append(par)
        content.append(div)
        entry.append(content)

        doc.append(entry)

    output = etree.tostring(doc, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
    return HttpResponse(output, mimetype="application/xhtml+xml")
```

**This is how the output should look:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns:ap="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/aptypes" xmlns:apxh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:apnm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apnm" xmlns:apcm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apcm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <entry>
    <content type="xhtml">
      <apxh:div>
        <apxh:p>This is some text</apxh:p>
        <apxh:p>This is text with a <apxh:a href="http://somewebsite.com">Link</apxh:a> in it.</apxh:p>
        <apxh:p>Theater</apxh:p>
      </apxh:div>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

**This is how the output currently looks:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns:ap="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/aptypes" xmlns:apxh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:apnm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apnm" xmlns:apcm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apcm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <entry>
    <content type="xhtml">
      <apxh:div>
        <apxh:p>This is some text</apxh:p>
        <apxh:p>This is text with a &lt;apxh:a href=\"http://somewebsite.com;\"&gt;Link Text;&lt;/apxh:a&gt; in it.</apxh:p>
        <apxh:p>Theater</apxh:p>
      </apxh:div>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding individual nodes instead of one big text node?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not sure I follow. Can you give me an example?

Comment: `div.append(node1); div.append(node2); div.append(node3)`

Comment: I believe that's basically what I'm doing because it appends it each time the loop runs.

Comment: Except you're using `par.text`. (Yes, I should have used `par` in my example, not `div`)

Comment: Maybe you can show me an example. I'm a n00b when it comes to Python so I may not understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: Any XML generator that rendered XML tags in the text without escaping them -- the way you're trying to do -- would be broken, because it would be able to write things that weren't valid XML, and content that contained literal text like `<foo:bar/>` wouldn't be round-tripped correctly, because parsing that written data back would interpret it as a tag, not as text.

Comment: ...so this isn't really about Python; it's about XML; you'd have the same problem with **any** compliant XML tools in **any** programming language.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I agree. I just wasn't sure how to accomplish this within Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inject your content as literal text -- render it into DOM content, with a namespace map that implicitly makes the default namespace the same one mapped to `aphx`:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
text='This is text with a <a href="http://somewebsite.com">Link</a> in it.'
text_el = etree.fromstring('<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' + text + '</root>')
```

...then put the contents of `text_el` inside your `par`.

Doing that might look like the following:

```
par = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div', nsmap=nm)
par.text = text_el.text
for child_el in text_el[:]:
  par.append(child_el)
```

Because the nsmap `nm` is used above, converting this back to a string will honor the namespace prefixes contained therein, thus using `apxh` for content left in the default namespace (which we mapped with `xmlns=` inside the artificial root).

---

In discussion in comments, it's come up that some of your production data looks like:

```
u'John Doe: 360-555-4546; <a href=\\"mailto:john.doe@website.com;\\">John.mailto:john.doe@website.com</a> twitter.com/JohnDoe'
```

`etree.fromstring()` will throw an exception when given this input, because it isn't valid XML (or valid XHTML), on account of the backslashes.

If you're quite sure that `\"` won't ever occur in valid input, you might consider:

```
text_el = etree.fromstring(
  '<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' +
  text.replace('\\"', '"') +
  '</root>')
```

Comment: I think the part where you talk about breaking the string up might be the r right path. A string can have multiple link in it too. If anyone could help guide me with this that would be great.

Comment: I updated my code locally to reflect what you sugguested but am just getting an error of "AttValue: " or ' expected, line 1, column 52". This is my code: http://labs.codecademy.com/Cm47#:workspace

Comment: ...to be clear, I tested this with `This is text with a <a href="http://somewebsite.com">Link</a> in it.`, and that's the only sample you've provided.

Comment: This is the data that fails: `u'John Doe: 360-555-4546; <a href=\\"mailto:john.doe@website.com;\\">John.mailto:john.doe@website.com</a> twitter.com/JohnDoe'`

Comment: The backslashes are a problem there. Does all your data have them?

Comment: ...I mean, you could use `lxml.html.fromstring()` instead of `etree.fromstring()`, and at least it'll parse without a failure, but then you'd have broken links, like `John Doe: 360-555-4546; <a href="\&quot;mailto:john.doe@website.com;\&quot;">John.mailto:john.doe@website.com</a> twitter.com/JohnDoe`. (You'd also need to switch your `etree` implementation to `lxml.etree`, if it isn't already).

Comment: Anyhow, if the resulting problem is one you only have when your data isn't valid XML, I'm tempted to call this question correctly answered. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't mark it correctly answered until I get it working and that hasn't happened yet. Also, I don't see your solution converting that anchor tags to `<apxh:a>` rather than `<a>`.

Comment: The conversion is implicit, because of the `xmlns=` (setting a default namespace) pointing to the same namespace defined as `apxh`. So -- you don't see it, but yes, it's there.

Comment: ...and it certainly works, **when given valid XHTML as input**. If your data is broken, how can you expect to inject it correctly? :)

Comment: I've updated this with a fix (which you should have written yourself) for the backslash issue. Obviously, data broken in different ways will need different fixes -- or perhaps you should just write an exception handler to discard data that doesn't parse.